# О колхозниках и совхозниках

Tags: общие-вопросы

Почему слово `колхозник` есть, а слова `совхозник` нет?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А без картинок - никак?

Answer (score 2):

Слово такое есть https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA

Оно малоупотребительно в силу своей ненужности. Колхозники - это социальный слой , едва ли не самостоятельный класс. А совхозники - кто? Чем вообще знаменита эта группа граждан СССР - кроме места работы?